# Multiple updates in MySQL for same table one query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

Is there a way to update multiple rows at once in single query in MySQL? Right now i have 4 queries for each condition. I want to combine all the following updates into one query with the best performance.

```
UPDATE rates SET timestamp = 1643655901, bnb = 'value1', eth = 'value2', usdc = 'value3' WHERE base = 'btc';
UPDATE rates SET timestamp = 1643655901, bnb = 'value4', btc = 'value5', usdc = 'value6' WHERE base = 'eth';
UPDATE rates SET timestamp = 1643655901, eth = 'value7', btc = 'value8', usdc = 'value9' WHERE base = 'bnb';
UPDATE rates SET timestamp = 1643655901, bnb = 'value10', btc = 'value11', eth = 'value12' WHERE base = 'usdc';
```

`timestamp` field can be same for any query

`value1 - value12` dynamic data based on different variables

I was looking into other answers on a similar question but have not been able to build the query, thanks for any help.

Comment: You could probably concoct a case expression but what you have is a lot easier to read and amend.

Comment: I'm not worried about reading, I would like to do it in one query, I've looked at CASE examples but did not find a similar case for me.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE rates`; then I may have a way using IODKU to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you might construct a *case expression* to combine into a single update (untested of course)

```
update rates set
    timestamp = 1643655901, 
    bnb = case base
        when 'btc' then 'value1'
        when 'eth' then 'value4'
        when 'bnb' then 'value7'
        else 'value10' end,
    etc = case base
        when 'btc' then 'value2'
        when 'eth' then 'value5'
        when 'bnb' then 'value8'
        else 'value11' end,
    usdc = case base
        when 'btc' then 'value3'
        when 'eth' then 'value6'
        when 'bnb' then 'value9'
        else 'value12' end
where base in ('btc', 'eth', 'bnb', 'usdc');
```